# How to make data zig zag from a,a,a,b,b,b to a,b,a,b,a,b using php or sort?

Tags: php, mysql, sorting, codeigniter

How to make data zig zag from a,a,a,b,b,b to a,b,a,b,a,b using php or sort?

because i'm try usort but it can't be done

Comment: this looks a homework or some practice question. Try to show what you did, because this involves lots of interesting basic concepts I suggest you try to do it yourself. The easiest way is to extract the data to each array and insert those data into the 3rd array.

Answer (score 1):

We can certainly do it in MySQL using sort. Here is one possible way to do it. But do try to get the hang of the row_id user varible trick yourself.

```
create table test(v char(1));
insert test values('a'),('a'),('a'),('b'),('b'),('b');

select v from
    (select v ,@a_id:=@a_id+1 as row_id from test,(select @a_id:=0) t1 where v='a' 
    union
    select v ,@b_id:=@b_id+1 as row_id from test,(select @b_id:=0) t2 where v='b') t
order by row_id,v;
```